# Travis CI not finding python3 on macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, cmake, travis-ci

I have the following `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: objective-c 

# macOS and Xcode Version
osx_image: xcode10

# Build dependencies
install:
  - brew install python3
  - ./fetchDependencies -v
```

Which has been running fine until now. However, one of the builds that the `fetchDependencies` bash script invokes now requires `python3` while running `cmake`, and we are seeing the following error in Travis:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.15", but
  required is at least "3" (found /usr/local/bin/python)
```

FWIW...the result of the `brew install python3` command on Travis is:

```
Warning: python 3.6.5_1 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 3.6.5_1, run `brew reinstall python`
```

**Edit:** Following the suggestions in the link in @SiadArdroumli comment, I modified `.travis.yml` to the following, but get the same error:

```
language: objective-c 

# macOS and Xcode Version
osx_image: xcode10

# Build dependencies
install:
  - brew install python3
  - pip3 install virtualenv
  - virtualenv -p python3 .
  - ./fetchDependencies -v
```

Why is `cmake` not finding `python3`...and what can we do about it?

Comment: There might be a problem with osx and python see https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/9929 Could you try using xcode8.3 instead or this solution https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/9929#issuecomment-500073011

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @SiadArdroumli. I tried the solution in the first link (see my edit above), but it didn't work. And unfortunately we can't revert to Xcode 8.3, as our code is constantly striving to use features in the latest Apple SDK's (we're already delving into Xcode 11 in beta).

Comment: But did you noticed the statement, that python is not supported by mac? https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/ Maybe you should switch to another vendor like https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/hello-world-macos/ and wait until travis will support python on mac again.

Comment: Yes...I recognize that Travis does not officially support python on macOS. However...Python2 has been working fine on Travis. Thanks for the suggestion of CircleCI. I'll keep it in mind. For now, we've managed to work around the issue by engaging a mock stage in the build process, when we run it in Travis, that avoids running the build stage that was breaking.

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question while searching for an answer myself.
I found a temporary solution that worked for me.

`/usr/local/bin/python` is actually an alias file

Under `/usr/local/bin/`, you will find `/usr/local/bin/python3` as well and it's also an alias file.

What I did was to rename `/usr/local/bin/python` to `/usr/local/bin/pythonx` (a temporary name)

And rename `/usr/local/bin/python3` to `/usr/local/bin/python`

After this switching, `cmake` will find `python` with the correct version and the rest should work.

But from what I read, a lot of Apple applications depends on `Python 2` to work properly, so after you get the `cmake` command work, you may need to switch them back to the original names to avoid unforeseeable side effects